# kurento startup errorEvent: Invalid URI when trying to connect

Tags: kurento

I have kurento with kurento media installed on a docker image, but when i try to open the video url with a browser (http://XXXX:XXX:XXX:XXX:YYY/?url=rtsp://usr:pwd@ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ.ZZZ/image)

i received kurento.tutorial.player.PlayerHandler  : ErrorEvent: Invalid URI response

The rtsp uri with vlc player works perfect, but not in a docker with kurento server.

Any ideas?

Regards